# How can I access a class name if I use import * in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Inside the head of `index.html`:

```
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

`user.js` file:

```
export default class User {

    constructor(name, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

}

export function printName(user) {
    console.log(`User's name is ${user.name}`);
}

export function printAge(user){
    console.log(`User is ${user.age} years old`);
}
```

This `main.js` would work:

```
import User, { printName, printAge } from '/user.js'
const user = new User('Bob', 11);
console.log(user)
printName(user)
```

But this would not work as it will not recognize the exported class

```
// name User if I use `import *` to import everything:
import * as MyUser from '/user.js'
const user = new MyUser.User('Bob', 11);
console.log(user)
printName(user)
```

This is the error I get: `Uncaught TypeError: MyUser.User is not a constructor`

Comment: Bergi's answer is of course correct but for maximum flexibility I recommend you change it to `export class MyUser {...}` and then later `export default MyUser`. Then your named import would work as you wrote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You default-exported the class, so it will be available as `MyUser.default` on the namespace object.

If you want to access it as `.User`, don't use a default export. I would recommend this for any module that exports multiple bindings (with a clear primary one). If it's important that a user can write `import User from …` instead of `import { User } from …`, you can also export the class under multiple names:

```
export class User {…}
export { User as default }
```